# Laravel Controller date query

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is my code in my controller:

```
public function getPublicPost($school_id){
    $public_feeds = app(AllyFeedRepository::class)->query()
    ->whereHas('user_detail', function($q){
        $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
    })
    ->with('user_detail:id,name,profile_photo_path,deleted_at','userInstance:id,user_id,role_id','userInstance.role:id,name','announcement:id,description,file_path,type,deleted_at')
    ->whereSchoolId($school_id)
    ->orWhere('school_id' ,'=', null)
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
    return $public_feeds;
}
```

then I add ->whereDate('deadline_viewing', '>=', now()) in my query suddenly I can't fetch the data

```
public function getPublicPost($school_id){
    $public_feeds = app(AllyFeedRepository::class)->query()
    ->whereHas('user_detail', function($q){
        $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
    })
    ->with('user_detail:id,name,profile_photo_path,deleted_at','userInstance:id,user_id,role_id','userInstance.role:id,name','announcement:id,description,file_path,type,deleted_at')
    ->whereSchoolId($school_id)
    ->orWhere('school_id' ,'=', null)
    ->whereDate('deadline_viewing', '>=', now())
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
    return $public_feeds;
}
```

I'm expecting I can fetch the data with that query

Comment: Can you provide us what is the error that you received?

Comment: I can't fetch the data like when I add that whereDate in my query

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `now()` function that produces a timestamp.
I believe you need to pass a date (or Carbon) object:

```
->whereDate('deadline_viewing', '>=', \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now())
```